# Can Android Drawables defined in XML contain a path?

Tags: java, android, svg

I use Inkscape to create the art assets in my app.

At the moment I have to create bitmaps from my (simple) Inkscape vector art before I can use the images in my app.

I would prefer to be able to create an XML Drawable that contains the paths from my art. Can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

Not directly, but there are some third-party workarounds. Have a look at [this guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/136239/Android-ImageView-and-Drawable-with-SVG-Support), for example.

Comment: Thanks for the link, unfortunately that requires native code which I'd rather avoid using.

Answer (score 3):

With the release of **Android 5.0 Lollipop** (API 21) this is now possible using [`VectorDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html)

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:height="64dp"
     android:width="64dp"
     android:viewportHeight="600"
     android:viewportWidth="600" >
     <group
         android:name="rotationGroup"
         android:pivotX="300.0"
         android:pivotY="300.0"
         android:rotation="45.0" >
         <path
             android:name="v"
             android:fillColor="#000000"
             android:pathData="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,70 0,0 -70,70z" />
     </group>
 </vector>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying the same thing.  This project has a pure Java impl.  It works OK for simple objects, but failed on some complicated objects.  It does have a method to convert SVG path Strings to Path objects...

https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/